# How would I calculate the maximum complexity of living system based on entropy increase acceleration?

Tags: entropy, complex-systems

Living systems locally decrease their own entropy by increasing the entropy of their environment by larger margin, creating a local minimum in entropy. The higher the complexity of the living system, the bigger local minimum in entropy and the higher the acceleration of increase in entropy in the entire system. (As life grows in complexity the universe decays faster.)

Given the finite energy in the closed system, at some point the entropy will increase to a point where the energy dispersement will not support life at the (then current) complexity and the complexity will start to decrease again and with it the acceleration of the entropy increase will go down, until all life will cease and there will be no local minima in entropy and it will increase uniformly, the heat death of the universe.

How would I calculate the distribution of the acceleration (of entropy increase) over the life of universe? Would the distribution be skewed? Could we place an upper bound on the acceleration and thus the maximum possible complexity of life?

Comment: You’re basically asking about an entire subfield of physics here. There are various inequalities and distributions for particular things in particular models.

Comment: “The distribution of the acceleration over the life of the universe” sounds like an extremely vaguely defined idea, and relating it to the “maximum possible complexity of life” sounds even vaguer. It sounds like some tech illiterate manager saying “can you make an algorithm that finds how profitable our company would be in 150 years?”

Comment: I think it's a very interesting question; however there are several factors that are very difficult to quantify. For example, how do we quantify 'complexity of life' and link that to entropy generation? Also, it would be necessary to take into account the population of the lifeforms, as well as make assumptions on whether they can travel inter-galactically (otherwise they can't access all the energy).

Comment: Measures of complexity are notoriously shaky; we do not have any agreed on measures that capture the concept well (Kolmogorov complexity is often useful, but gives maximal complexity to random strings). It seems that you need to define a more detailed model of the life to start doing the calculation. For example, see the work of Adami and Ofria on the Avida model of thermodynamics of evolution. Using such a model you might be able to calculate an acceleration.

Comment: I looked up all possible ways to look at the complexity including Kolmogorov, but that does not lead anywhere. So instead of creating a model and looking at how it grows, I am trying to see if I can put some constraint on how it "can" grow. Will the growth be gradual or accelerate in leaps through singularity? That is too hard to answer. But maybe the collapse might be a better place to focus on? In the end the acceleration in entropy increase might be useful upper bound measure and I'm wondering what can be said about it, if anything.

Comment: What I mean about focusing on the collapse: Did anyone study how quickly life accelerates entropy increase in current stages of complexity? How quickly it happened at lower complexity? Do we know anything about the early part of the curve? Did anyone study or model collapse from current complexity down to zero to see the end of the curve? Can those two be compared? Based on current distribution of matter and energy in universe, are there some other things -purely from mathematics - that we could learn about the middle part?